# How to share a calendar between users on Baikal?

Tags: caldav, sabredav

I have a Baikal server installed, I have two users: Bob and Alice. I want to share Bob's calendar with Alice.

I tried to go to `my.baikal/dav.php/calendars/bob/calendar-to-share/` (which is the Sabre/Dav interface) and to give Alice access by using the Share this ressource form with no success.

I tried to use:

- Alice email: `mailto:alice@email.dd`
- Alice profile link: /dav.php/principals/alice

The `d:invite` node now looks like:

```
 <d:sharee>
  <d:href>/dav.php/principals/bob</d:href>
  <d:prop/>
  <d:share-access>
   <d:not-shared/>
  </d:share-access>
  <d:invite-accepted/>
 </d:sharee>
 <d:sharee>
  <d:href>/dav.php/principals/alice</d:href>
  <d:prop/>
  <d:share-access>
   <d:read-write/>
  </d:share-access>
  <d:invite-invalid/>
 </d:sharee>
 <d:sharee>
  <d:href>mailto:alice@email.dd</d:href>
  <d:prop/>
  <d:share-access>
   <d:read-write/>
  </d:share-access>
  <d:invite-accepted/>
 </d:sharee>
```

but Alice can't get access to Bob's calendar.

Comment: I have the same probblem, starting a bounty...